# Why give individual li elements a class for main nav bar?

Tags: html

I'm reading HTML on some large websites just to see how others assemble their code. On playmonopoly.us (and many other sites) the main navigation bar is created with li classes.

Question:

- If a `li` element is only one out of several on a main nav bar, why would someone want to use a class for each `li` element?
- What exact benefit does having classes for each `li` give?

Wouldn't it make more sense to give each `ul` a class, then target each ul within CSS if styling the li element was the goal of creating classes? What am I missing with the whole `li` class thing?

Comment: loving that you are asking why and that you are looking at the source code of other sites to increase your knowledge. Keep on learning and NEVER stop asking why! Well done Al.

Comment: Thanks gavgrif for taking the time to explain that. It makes perfect sense. Now I'll have to think of ways to use this new knowledge on sites I'm building!

Answer (score 1):

One role of giving a class to a navigation li is to display which li is the active one for page navigation. This might be a different colouor  or different background to demonstrate that the link is the active page.

This can be done easily in php, in which the active page is named prior to calling the header / nav.

for example - setting the active page variable:

```
<?php $activePage="home";?>
```

// other code related to the nav menu
//include the common header / nav file

```
<li class="<?php if($activePage =="home"){echo"active";}?>"><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
```

What this does is allow a common nave menu that then indicates the active page you are on and can therefore be styled accordingly. And each page in the nav menu can have the active class if it is the active page. Therefore there is a single nav menu that performs differently on different pages according to the setting of the activePage class.

Incidentally- the $activePage variable can be used in the footer as well if you have navigation elements in the footer - and can therefore allow styling of the active page link at the top and bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason to give each li a class is when using javascript/jquery with your navigation:

If you're doing a lot of manipulation, performance may be an issue, so instead of writing

```
ul.main-nav > li
```

all the time, you're better off with:

```
.main-nav-item
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful later for scripting. 
And it depends on you preferences.
You can set an id or a class for `<ul>` or `<ol>` and then stylize `<li>`using `li:nth-child()` option.
You'll be able to stylize all `<li>` if you need the same parameters without typing `li:nth-child()` each time by defining a class, though.